# Block post updates and deletion after a set period

Tags: date-time

Trying to adapt the code from [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-block-wordpress-post-updates-and-deletion-after-a-set-period/) to my use case:

```
function wpbeginner_restrict_editing( $allcaps, $cap, $args ) {

    // Bail out if we're not asking to edit or delete a post ...
    if( 'edit_post' != $args[0] && 'delete_post' != $args[0]
      // ... or user is admin
      || !empty( $allcaps['manage_options'] )
      // ... or user already cannot edit the post
      || empty( $allcaps['edit_posts'] ) )
        return $allcaps;

    // Load the post data:
    $post = get_post( $args[2] );

    // Bail out if the post isn't published:
    if( 'publish' != $post->post_status )
        return $allcaps;

    //if post is older than 30 days. Change it to meet your needs
    if( strtotime( $post->post_date ) < strtotime( '-30 day' ) ) {
         //Then disallow editing.
         $allcaps[$cap[0]] = FALSE;
    }
    return $allcaps;
}
add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'wpbeginner_restrict_editing', 10, 3 );
```

This works great, however how do I use seconds or minutes, not days? Say, '-300 seconds' doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) acceptable units for `strtotime()` are:

```
unit    (('sec' | 'second' | 'min' | 'minute' | 'hour' | 'day' | 'fortnight' | 'forthnight' | 'month' | 'year') 's'?) | 'weeks' | daytext
```

Try using `-300 second` (not `seconds`).

Comment: Yes I had tried 'second' and it didn't work. However now that I've played with it some more, I can report that `-240 minute` works as expected, while `-180 minute` doesn't. The post I'm testing was published 12 minutes ago. What could this be about? Could this be related to my timezone in WP being set to UTC-3?